# Anyone familiar with dd-wrt scripting?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

My router will randomly lose connection to everything.
I can't ping it, it has no internet, I can't even get to the setup page through a wired connection.
It won't fix until I unplug it and plug it back in.
This happens a lot. It happened four times in the past 45 minutes/
Maybe it's a broken router, but I got it in November, and I don't have any other issues with it other than being forced to unplug it. 
So I'm wondering, can I make some kind of script that will check if the router has communication, and if it doesn't then it reboots it? 
I know dd-wrt has a built in function to do a scheduled reboot, but that doesn't help me.
If the router goes out right now, and it's scheduled to reboot every three hours, that doesn't really solve my problem.

I have a  Linksys E1200 v1  with DD-WRT v24-sp2 (04/07/12) mini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work(or be a step in the right direction) have it run on startup,

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 #Note: depending on software version it might be ping -n 1
    con=$? #Get exit code, anything other than 0 is bad
    if [ $con -ne 0 ]; then #If con doesn't equal 0 then
        reboot #This one is pretty obvious
    fi
    sleep 60 #Wait a minute between checks
done
```

Comment: Its a good script, but I would put in a much longer sleep period - why tie up all the CPU doing pings, when doing the same thing every 30 or 60 seconds - or even running this script every minute from crontab rather then as a shell on startup could do the same thing.

Comment: @davidgo Good point, I hadn't even considered crontab, my script can easily be adapted though if needed.

Comment: I tried that script and it put my router into a boot loop.

Comment: @breebreebran If any error occures in the ping command then it will reboot, test `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` by itself to make sure you don't need -n instead of -c.

Comment: I'm curious, what is 8.8.8.8?
Shouldn't that be the default gateway instead? 
192.168.1.1
Because when the default gateway can't be reached, nothing can communicate.

Comment: @breebreebran 8.8.8.8 is Google's DNS(Which is the best test of internet connect), I didn't use the default gateway because that could just be pinging the router itself depending on your setup.

Comment: Is there a way to make the start up of that script delayed?
I might be wrong, but I think it put my router into a boot loop because it takes a few minutes for my router to fully start up. And I think it's trying to ping that dns before it establishes an internet connection. So since it has no internet at that moment it can't ping google which puts it in that boot cycle. Am I wrong?

Comment: @breebreebran You may be correct, add `sleep 180` to the beginning of the script(before `while true; do` and after `#!/bin/bash`) and it will wait three minutes before checking internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

DD-wrt also has a [watchdog feature](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=73521) that looks like it would do exactly as you want.